# On Matrix polar decomposition and absolute value operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The polar decomposition for complex matrices is $A=OP$ where $O$ is a partial isometry and $P$ is (hermitian) positive semidefinite. In other notations the matrix P is considered as an absolute value operator for A, i.e. $P=|A|=(A^TA)^{1/2}$ where $(\cdot)^{1/2}$ is the principle square root operator.
Can we apply the triangular inequality with $|\cdot|$ for matrices, i.e., $|X-Y|=\Big((X-Y)^T(X-Y)\Big)^{1/2}\leq(X^TX)^{1/2}+(Y^TY)^{1/2}=|X|+|Y|$.

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are asking.  Are you viewing the inequality $|X-Y| \leq |X| + |Y|$ as $|X| + |Y| - |XY| \geq 0$ is a positive operator or are you considering the inequality with respect to some norm?

Comment: As $|\cdot|$ was defined as the HPSD factor of the polar decomposition, what would be the meaning of $|X-Y|\leq|X|+|Y|$?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel As you said $|\cdot|$ is the HPSD factor where for any matrix $A$ we have $|A|=(A^TA)^{1/2}$. I am wondering if we can consider that $|\cdot|$ operator as a norm, hence we can apply the triangular property.. so $|X-Y|=\Big((X-Y)^T(X-Y)\Big)^{1/2}\leq(X^TX)^{1/2}+(Y^TY)^{1/2}=|X|+|Y|$.

Comment: @MustafaSaid: $|\cdot|$ is the operator that I have defined as $|A|=(A^TA)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Bel Ok but how do you define $\leq$ for matrices? (which is btw the point of the first two comments)

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: The inequality should be elementwise (entries of matrices).

Comment: @Bel This is not true, e.g., consider $X=\begin{bmatrix}0&-5\\4&4\end{bmatrix}$, $Y=\begin{bmatrix}1&-3\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $|X-Y|-|X|-|Y|=\begin{bmatrix}0&10\\-4&2\end{bmatrix}$.